# Changing text color using replace method

Tags: javascript, jquery, str-replace

I am using the following code inside my click handler (shown in JSFiddle below) to replace a text when a user clicks on a cell value:

```
  var value = event.args.value;
  var color = "#FF0000";

  var highlighted = text.replace(
                ' ' + value + ' ', 
                "<span style='color:" + color + ";'</span> "
              );

  panel.jqxPanel('clearcontent');
  panel.jqxPanel('append', highlighted);
```

Q1: 
It is behaving in a different manner. I mean when I click on the first cell value, it converts everything to red color, clicking on other values makes it behave in different manner as can be seen in my JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/b35q3gxv/33/)

Q2. What can I use to preserve the html formatting? I mean using `var text = panel.html();` instead of `var text = panel.text();` didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the closing `>` on your span tag, and you are omitting the `value` that you obtained from `var value = event.args.value;` so the word goes missing.

```
var highlighted = text.replace(
            ' ' + value + ' ', 
            ' <span style="color:' + color + ';">' + value + '</span> '
//                                              ^    ^^^^^
```

Note I also changed the quote characters used so the HTML can have the double-quotes `"` which are more commonly used in markup, and javascript doesn't care about single or double quotes for strings — use whichever you like, just be consistent, for your own sanity.

Try the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stephen61/b35q3gxv/35/) I created, changing only that line, and you will see the word you click on get highlighted.

---

That said, it is generally better to avoid inline styles like `color="#FF0000"` and use classes and CSS styles for them instead. You could instead have simpler code that doesn't have to work the var `color` into it:

```
var highlighted = text.replace(
            ' ' + value + ' ', 
            ' <span class="selected">' + value + '</span> '
```

Your CSS would have a rule `span.selected { color: #FF0000; }` ... then, restyling your highlight color from red to something else you just change the CSS instead of having to change your javascript code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you by any chance know, what should I do to preserve the formatting of HTML?

Comment: If I put formatted code inside `<pre>` tag for html, do you know why it stops working? Let me know if you need JSfiddle of what I am referring to?

Comment: @John I'm not sure what you meant in Q2, or what you mean now.  When you are doing your `text.replace` that is happening in the browser, not the original HTML source, so formatting/layout of the actual HTML text source is irrelevant.  If that's _not_ what you mean, maybe you should start a new question where you can give a lot of detail.

Comment: Nice answer. Just one note: HTML does not "prefer" double quotes around attribute values. They are probably more commonly used than single quotes, but [single and double quotes are equally valid](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2).

Comment: Thanks @MichaelGeary - you're right of course. Changed in my answer.